# Recover previously saved files after blue screen in Win8

Tags: windows-8, bsod, visual-studio-2010, file-recovery

Earlier today Windows 8 blue-screened while I was working on some CSS animations, when I rebooted I found that the CSS file I had been working on and that was open in Visual Studio was blank. I don't expect to get any unsaved changes back of course, but what happened to the rest of the file that was there and saved long before? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Looks like the file contents got corrupted for some reason when the BSOD occurred. Short of using data recovery software and hoping for the best there's not much else you can do.

Comment: Weird thing is it's blank, I've never seen a file get wiped like that completely. Usually they just look like a bunch of random characters when they're corrupted. Guess it's just another typical Windows issue. Thanks for the reply though.